# Python error in functions

Tags: python-2.7

I am an absolute beginner in python. I was practicing simple python code of functions from a tutorial. But I am getting some wierd error when i try running this code snippet from terminal. What is the role of main in this can someone explain me?

```
def donuts(count):
  if count < 10:
    return 'Number of donuts: ' +str(count)
  else:
    return 'Number of donuts: many'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: "some weird error" isn't useful information. Please post the actual stack trace whenever you have one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For every future question you ever ask on this site, make sure you copy the error message from your screen and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` is the conventional name for a function to run when a file is executed as a script. However, it's not magic; you still need to define what `main` is, or Python will throw a `NameError` at you. If you want to run `donuts`, have `main` run `donuts`:

```
def donuts(count):
  if count < 10:
    return 'Number of donuts: ' +str(count)
  else:
    return 'Number of donuts: many'

def main():
    print donuts(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: so does it mean in this case the last line should be changed to donuts(count) @user2357112

Comment: @Kishan: That'd give a `NameError`, since you haven't actually specified a count.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the main function is usually created to aggregate all the defined functions into one. Implying that `main()` is used to call all other functions. Seems like you're calling main but main isn't defined.

Rule of thumb, always define a function before you call it.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what a noob me was looking at that time.